# How to read tab separated file in C?

Tags: c, arrays, struct, scanf

So I have a file of records that are separated by spaces.  It looks like this:

```
Name[Tab]Number 
Name[Tab]Number 
Name[Tab]Number
```

I also have a structure:

```
typedef struct {
    char name[50];
    int number;
} Record;
```

I have an array of Records and I want to read the file in.  When I do this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    fscanf(filePointer, "%s\t%d\n", recordArray[i].name, recordArray[i].number);
}
```

Everything in the file is read as 0.  What am I doing wrong?

Edit: Changed to this and it still didn't work:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    fscanf(filePointer, " %s %d", recordArray[i].name, &recordArray[i].number);
}
```

By doing some debugging, I found that if I set each one manually, like so:

```
recordArray[0] = (Record) { "Name", 0 };
```

It works, and I can print it out like this:

```
printf("%s %d\n", recordArray[0].name, recordArray[0].number);
```

Which gives the output:

```
Name Number
```

However, if I use fscanf and print out the same record, like so:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    fscanf(filePointer, " %s %d", recordArray[i].name, &recordArray[i].number);
}
printf("%s %d\n", recordArray[0].name, recordArray[0].number);
```

I get the output:

```
0
```

I'm still not sure what's going on.

Comment: try: `fscanf(filePointer, " %s %d", recordArray[i].name, &recordArray[i].number);`

Comment: For the `scanf` family of functions, any whitespace in the directive means "matches any amount of white space, including none, in the input". Also, you forgot `&` for the last parameter.

Comment: @kaylum — since both `%s` and `%d` skip leading white space automatically, adding the spaces to the format string won't make any difference.  However, adding the `&` before the number most certainly does matter.

Comment: Can the names contain spaces?  If so, you need to use a scan set to read the name: `%49[^\t]` would look for up to 49 non-tabs, stopping at a tab.  Then the `%d` would skip the tab (white space) and read the number.  But you must use `&recordArray[i].number` for the number argument.

Comment: That did not work.  I don't understand!

Answer (score 0):

For anybody who cares:
Earlier in the function, I had checked the number of lines in the file and forgotten to rewind the file pointer.  This was causing `fscanf()` to return `-1` `(EOF)` because the file pointer had already moved past the data.  `"%s %d"` is the correct formatter for what I was trying to do, and I made sure to prepend `&` to `recordArray[i].number`.